# How to assert presence of java applet using selenium?

Tags: testing, selenium, automation

Does anyone know how to verify presence of java applet using Selenium IDE. I want to verify the presence of Ephox text editor in a form, so I can verify the element but how do I assert that it is Ephox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the Ephox editor, but to answer your java applet question: you could just have selenium verify that the element is present.

So if the applet was contained in this tag:

```
<applet width="81" height="120" name="clock1" code="tz.class" codebase="applets/" style="background-color: transparent;">
```

I would use the below code in Selenium IDE to verify that it's present.

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
    <td>css=applet</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Cheers,
Sam

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I can now verify the presence but can you please tell me how i can type the text in it as selenium IDE doesnt record & even adding the scripts like above doesnt help... for checking Ephox you can check the following link: http://editlive.com/demo

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think Selenium is meant to interact with applets to the degree you are looking for. Why not just use a tool specifically made for that? Google it and I'm sure you'll find some. If you insist on still using Selenium, maybe commands like mouseDownAt  will help you.